# Apt and Python Errors

Tags: apt, python

Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS Jammy

Something is very wrong with Apt, or python. I have no idea how to troubleshoot this. I've tried re-installing several versions of python, and re-installing software-properties-common. I've seen questions and answers related to other problems, but none of them apply or are many years old--trying such solutions would be dangerous.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 15, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.shortcuthandler import ShortcutException
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuthandler.py", line 26, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.extendedsourceslist import (SourceEntry,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/extendedsourceslist.py", line 436
    def __init__(self, sourceslist=None, /, files=None):
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Have you changed the default python3 version?  You mention "*several versions of python*" where the default should not be changed if you want to reply on package front-end tools like that command, as they'll misbehave. I'd suggest restoring the default `python3` back to default.

Comment: @guiverc This was the problem. Thanks! I had some weird symlink issues with /etc/alternatives involving python3. Replacing the bad symlink fixed a number of python related issues. You really saved me here, but as your reply isn't an answer, I'm unsure of how to mark it as accepted. (Newish to stackexchange)

Comment: Nah sorry; but you understand Stack Exchange well; ie. accepting an answer; but I left only a comment. I've tagged the question as '*not-reproducible, problem went away thus unlikely to help future readers*' as I'm sure there will be multiple answers here already on fixing changes to default python (*it's a common mistake*).  I'm glad you got it solved; but if you'd like some SE *rep*, write up your own answer (*and you can accept it in time*) & you can reference my *comment* or *hint* if it was helpful & you like.